# Should I explicitly lock table rows to execute a DELETE?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

Mysql InnoDB docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html) state that:

> A locking read, an UPDATE, or a DELETE generally set record locks on every index record that is scanned in the processing of the SQL statement.

But I'm not sure if this is enough to prevent race conditions with multiple concurrent mysql sessions, some performing SELECT, others UPDATE, and yet others DELETE.

I was thinking of doing a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE before I executed my DELETE, but I'm not sure if this is good practice - or even necessary.

Comment: No, you should not do that. There's nothing you can do, using any kind of statement from any type of language that will improve anything that MySQL does already. If anything happens while MySQL attempts the delete, you'll receive an error - this is a clear sign that you should retry the transaction (in your case, a `DELETE`). At most, all you can achieve by manually setting locks is that you'll screw up. The rule in concurrent access to MySQL is that you attempt to perform a query and if it fails - you retry (for X amount of times before giving up, if you decide to do so).

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2014/12/08/eventual-consistency-simpler-than-mvcc/ as well. The short answer is you probably shouldn't try to manage this concurrency yourself and MySQL is doing a lot of work to manage it for you. The longer answer is, take a long, hard look at MVCC (eg http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html)